# Using itertools in python, plot periodic equation

Tags: python, plot, python-itertools

I want to draw a function which has periodic condition.
My code is as following.

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from numpy import *

import itertools

from itertools import *

r = np.linspace(-1, 1, 1000)

f(r) = np.exp(-pow(r,2)/5)
```

In this situation, the period of `f(r)` equals 2. I want to plot `(r,f(r))` in the range `-inf < r < 1`.

With using itertools.repeat, how can I plot that figure?

Answer (score 0):

`f(r) = np.exp(-pow(r,2)/5)` isn't valid python. Just try `print np.exp(-pow(r, 2)/5)`.  Or `def f(r): return np.exp(-pow(r, 2)/5)`

`from numpy import *` does nothing for below it.

`from itertools import *` does nothing below for below it.

Imports are in the form of:

```
import blah
blah.blah_function()
```

or

```
from blah import blah_function
blah_function()
```

or (don't do this... ever... please)

```
from blah import *
blah_function()
```

also

`float('inf')`, `-float('inf')`, and `float('-inf')` are all valid in python.